# ThreadPoolExecutor not consuming data

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I have setup a ThreadPoolExecutor and start the threads to consume data from the blocking queue. 
On startup (when I call startThread below), the blocking queue is empty. 
I've set the timeout for the threads to be very large so that they don't die. 
The blocking queue is created outside the scope of WorkerThreadPoolExecutor, and Runnable items are put on it.

```
public class WorkerThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final MyBlockingQueue<MyRunnable> blockingQueue;
    private ScheduledExecutorService statsExecutor = null;

    public WorkerThreadPoolExecutor(MyBlockingQueue myBlockingQueue) {

        super(5, 10, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES, myBlockingQueue);
        this.blockingQueue = myBlockingQueue;

    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        logger.info("Shutting down the stats emitter!");
        super.shutdown();
        if (statsExecutor != null) {
            statsExecutor.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public void startThreads() {
        logger.info("Starting the WorkerThreadPoolExecutor!!!");
        this.prestartCoreThread();
        emitStats();
    }

    public void numThds() {
        System.err.println("\t\t active: " + this.getActiveCount());
        System.err.println("\t\t completed taskCount: " + this.getCompletedTaskCount());
        System.err.println("\t\t core: " + this.getCorePoolSize());
        System.err.println("\t\t poolsize: " + this.getPoolSize());
        System.err.println("\t\t taskCount: " + this.getTaskCount());
        System.err.println("\t\t Q-Size: " + this.getQueue().size());

        //System.err.println("X Size is: -------------> " + blockingQueue.currentSize());
        System.err.println("X Size is: -------------> " + blockingQueue.getBlockingQueue().size());
        System.err.println("X Size is: -------------> " + this.getQueue().size());
    }

    public void emitStats() {

        this.statsExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        final Runnable emitStats = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.err.println("Stats id: " + blockingQueue.id);
                //System.err.println("Size is: -------------> " + blockingQueue.currentSize());
                System.err.println("Stats size is: -------------> " + blockingQueue.getBlockingQueue().size());

                numThds();
            }
        };
        statsExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(emitStats, 2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

The blocking queue is created outside the scope above and items put on it:

```
BlockingQueue<MyRunnable> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue()
```

Items are added to the queue to be processed, but they are never dequeued. 
I added metrics for stats that produced the following result:

```
Stats size is: -------------> 2
     active: 0
     completed taskCount: 0
     core: 5
     poolsize: 0
     taskCount: 2
     Q-Size: 2
X Size is: -------------> 2
X Size is: -------------> 2
```

How can I force the items to be taken off of the blocking queue and executed?

The code for MyRunnalbe is:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int x;
    public MyRunnable(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("----> " + x);
    }
}
```

I create an instance of it by calling:

```
 MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable(3);
```

and is enqueued by calling:

```
blockingQueue.add(mr);
```

Comment: It seems at though the active thread count being 0 is suspect!

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- there is absolutely no need to create a new executor service during each call to emitStats(). To the contrary, that contradicts the whole idea of such a service.
- there is no code in your example that would actually consume elements from tgat queue. Printing its size doesn't change the queue!

Comment: 1. I added emitStats to see what was going on over time
2. items put on the blocking queue are runnable; shouldn't the thread pool block on the queue and a thread grab and item from the queue and execute it once it dequeues it?

Comment: The threads do whatever you instructed them to do. Again: you are not showing any code that would do that. Computers do not work by magic - they exactly do what your code tells them to do.

Comment: The issue seems here that the pool size is 0 and i can't seem to (re?)start them.